# Proof for method to calculate Carmichael's $\lambda$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like the proof if $ w$ has prime factorization $2^{w_1}\cdot3^{w_2}\dots p_n^{w_n}$ then $\lambda(w)=\rm\,lcm\, (\lambda(2^{w_1}),\lambda(3^{w_2}),\dots,\lambda(p_n^{w_n})$

Is there a way to calculate $\lambda(p^k)$ rapidly for prime p?

Thank you very much, regards and Happy New Year!

Comment: You can find them in Section 12-6 of "Number Theory and its History" by O. Ore. Also, the second one is apparently true only for $p=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, it suffices to prove that $\lambda(st)=\mathrm{lcm}(\lambda(s),\lambda(t))$ if $\gcd(s,t)=1$.
Consider any $a$ such that $\gcd(a,st)=1$ and set $S=\lambda(s)$, $T=\lambda(t)$, $L=\mathrm{lcm}(S,T)$.

$S$ and $T$ satisfy the Carmichael congruence for $s$ and $t$ respectively. Since they divide $L$, we have: 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
a^L \equiv a^{S\cdot(L/S)}\equiv 1^{L/S}\equiv 1\pmod s \\
a^L \equiv a^{T\cdot(L/T)}\equiv 1^{L/T}\equiv 1\pmod t \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Chinese Remainder Theorem then tells us that $a^L \equiv 1\pmod{st}$.

Thus, $L$ satisfies the Carmichael condition for $(st)$, it might just not be the smallest positive integer with this property. However, we know that $S$ and $T$ *are* the smallest ones satisfying it for $s$ and $t$, so there must be exist integers $a_s$ and $a_t$ such that $$\begin{eqnarray}
1\leq k < S & \Rightarrow & a_s^k\not\equiv 1\pmod s \\
1\leq k < T & \Rightarrow & a_t^k\not\equiv 1\pmod t \\
\end{eqnarray}$$ Chinese Remainder Theorem then gives us a number $a$ satisfying
$$\begin{eqnarray}
a & \equiv & a_s \pmod s \\
a & \equiv & a_t \pmod t \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

If $1\leq k<L$, $k$ cannot be congruent to zero both modulo $s$ and modulo $t$; without loss of generality the non-congruent one will be $s$. Then, $a^k\equiv a_s^k \equiv a_s^{k\ \bmod\ S}\not\equiv 1\pmod s$. But this implies $a^k\not\equiv 1\pmod{st}$, so $k$ does not satisfy Carmichael condition.

Therefore, $\lambda(st)$ is indeed equal to $L=\mathrm{lcm}(\lambda(s),\lambda(t))$.

---

As it turns out, calculating $\lambda(p^k)$ is quite easy too:

$$\lambda(p^k) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}\phi(p^k)=2^{k-2} & \Leftarrow & p=2 \wedge k \geq 3 \\ 
\phi(p^k)=(p-1)p^{k-1} & \Leftarrow & p\not=2 \vee k < 3 \\ 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Great solution, thank you, only the use of the word set when you say set $S=\lambda(s)$ really had me thinking ;what set is he talking about? Can you prove the last part?